# Json.net Deserialize Array of Array of classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am receiving JSON data via URL as the following:

```
 {
       "destination_addresses" : [ "example address" ],
       "origin_addresses" : [ "example address" ],
       "rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "220 ft",
                      "value" : 67
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "1 min",
                      "value" : 12
                   },
                   "status" : "OK"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

I am trying to Deserialize to the following classes:

```
public class APIDistance
        {
    
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public string[] destination_addresses { get; set; }
            public string[] origin_addresses { get; set; }
            public Row[] rows { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Row
        {
            public Element[] elements { get; set; }
        }

        public class Element
        {
            public Distance distance { get; set; }
            public Duration duration { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Distance
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Duration
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
        }

   }
```

My issue is that I have no idea how to assign and/or read the data to or from the class. I have followed examples that suggest you should use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and then use the object to get the property required, however, I don't appear to be able to find any properties:
[image]

Was told to use newtonsoft as that is "Easy", but not found any examples of the Json structure I am trying to use.

New to Json so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `public class APIDistance {` which here is just functioning as a parent for nested classes. Instead deserialize `Rootobject` like this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json)`

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, paste them in as text

Comment: Thank you Charlieface! Works as I was expecting it to. I will avoid pictures of code in future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Remove public class APIDistance { which here is just functioning as a
> parent for nested classes. Instead deserialize Rootobject like this
> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) – Charlieface 18 mins ago